# Binding any possible alphabet letter or using a KeyListener?

Tags: java

I need to get the keyboard input for any alphabet letter in any language. I have already created a dirty example with KeyListener that works ok, but the key binding sounds very interesting. The problem with the key binding is that it looks like I need to manually bind each key with an action, something that is virtually impossible in my case, because the application needs to get input characters in many languages.

So, is there any way to create a binding with something like ANY_ALPHABETICAL_KEY?

Thanks in advance.

PS: This is not a duplicate :)

Comment: Your question would be much more meaningful with some code

Comment: `I need to get the keyboard input for any alphabet letter in any language.` - Why? What is your exact requirement. Is this for all components or a specific text component?

Comment: @camickr: Is for a specific component for a dictionary. A user can type a word in any language (in the style of Google Translate), and that input needs to be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key Bindings are for individual keys only. Yes you would need to bind every key with an Action so it is not a good choice.

If you need to listen for the entire keyboard, then use a KeyListener or maybe one of the ideas from [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) will help.

Without a more specific requirement we are just guessing.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that the listener will be a good choice in this case. Thanks. I have some actions for arrows, would you recommend to create bindings for them or doing everything with the listener?

Comment: Don't force a listener to do multiple functions. I would create Actions for specific functions. So for the arrows I would use Key Bindings.